# Difference between yaw angle and slip angle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, terminology, rotational-kinematics

What's the difference between slip angle and yaw angle (speaking about cars)? It seems they both are the angle between the actual direction of travel and the direction towards which it is pointing.

Comment: Cars yaw, tires slip.

Answer (score 1):

Yaw is typically just the heading of the aircraft on the compass.

Sideslip is the relative angle between the freestream flow and the aircraft yaw vector (to simplify it somewhat). Sideslip is the analog of angle of attack, but for yaw instead of pitch.

Comment: The OP specifies *"speaking about cars"*, so a discussion of aircraft beahvcior seems unresponsive, no?

Comment: I was trying to give a slight idea what those two angles are.Exactly it is not the best answer

Comment: I found this answer on the internet but I still don't understand